# Article itemtype Product not allowed in AMP-HTML?

Tags: amp-html

On Google Search Console I am getting error AMP validating: Missing required structured data element on this amp page.

Page has: 
And Page pass structure data testing toool

It is not allowed itemtype Product?

Comment: Could you provide a URL to your page so I can take a look?

Comment: https:// www. alpel.es/cosmo-nails-liquido-porcelana-uv-50-ml_amp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a quick look and it appears you are missing some properties. Check Google's documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews) for the required properties. Also, just a recommendation, you should use the JSON-LD markup as it plays better with AMP. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Itemtype is not a substitute for the JSON-LD equivalent. You can use itemtype on HTML elements but you must declare the meaning of the AMP page using JSON-LD and schema.org terms. Your page may be valid on Google Structured Data Testing Tool, but not AMP valid. However, if it is AMP-valid, it also will be valid on Google SDTT.